# Problems using Text Input Component

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to create a math game, in Adobe Animate, where there is a question and the user types the answer into a text input bar.

I have created my submit button, and added an event listener, however, i am not sure how to compare the input text, and the result, using an `If` statement.

I have named my text input `"myname"` and here is my code so far:

```
this.submit.addEventListener("click", check);
function check()
{}
```

How do i get the input text and compare it to the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Equality `==` operator to check if they are same (equal)...

```
function check()
{
    if (myname.text == "your result text")
    {
        trace("user input (myname) is matching...");
    }

}
```

regarding...

> *"Sorry but this doesn't seem to be working it's not showing any errors it's just no showing the result or printing."*

I wonder if this line is causing a problem:

```
this.submit.addEventListener("click", check);
```

If you have a Sprite or MovieClip object called (instance name) "submit" then setup code like this:

```
submit.buttonMode = true;
submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, check);
```

Then let the compiler know that `function check` is supposed to handle mouse events.

```
function check (evt:MouseEvent)
{
    if (myname.text == "your result text")
    {
        trace("user input (myname) is matching...");
    }

}
```

PS: I personally don't use `this.` in front of variable names, but maybe your program setup means you have no choice. In such case, try using `this.submit.addEvent...` and `this.myname.text ==...` when trying to make it work.

Comment: sorry but this doesn't seem to be working it's not showing any errors it's just no showing the result or printing.